# Using java.awt.Desktop inside Alexa Skill's Intent handler

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing my firsts skills using ask-sdk-java and Skillservlet. I have successfully implemented my custom skill handler and communication with alexa.

Now I would like to run some code inside the handler, like opening a web browser using java.awt.Desktop:

```
public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input){
 
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
 
        String speechText = "Of course";
        return input.getResponseBuilder()
                .withSpeech(speechText)
                .build();
}
```

I am building it as a .war file and running into tomcat server.

When calling the intent, I receive the alexa response, but no web browser is opened.

It is possible to achieve this?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Not clear where you are expecting a browser window to open, even if it could.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the browser to open on the server running the skill or on your Echo device? ASK-SDK is server side and your response to the device will always be mediated by the Alexa Voice Service. You cannot run arbitrary Java code on a customer device.

You can run HTML and JavaScript in a response, but only using the Alexa Web API for Games, and only on devices that support it.

Comment: Hi @LetMyPeopleCode,                                                                                                              I am running the tomcat server on a PC with Windows. I would like to open the browser ont  the PC

Comment: That's more a Java/Tomcat question. If you get no answer, rephrase it without Alexa... Generically. You may be driving away people who could answer because they think "I don't know anything about Alexa." But Alexa in this instance is probably just a distraction from figuring out the Tomcat question.